# Interpreting the Packets using sharppcap

Tags: packet-capture, packet-sniffers, sharppcap

Is it possible to interpret  every coming packets using sharppcap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep.

SharpPcap uses Packet.Net, http://packetnet.sf.net, as it's packet dissector. Most common packet types are being processed. If you find one that isn't just let me know or open a feature request on the Packet.Net sourceforge tracker.

Sharppcap and Packet.net are also designed to be as fast as possible. You should be able to capture and process at network data rates in excess of 3MB/s without dropped packets.

Chris

Author of SharpPcap and Packet.Net

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider using [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com).